# Unicode URL HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()

Tags: servlets, unicode, httpresponse

My scenario is I store a Unicode URL in a cookie and get it in another servlet. And want to redirect it to this URL.

When I store it in cookie I used the following code :

```
httpResponse.addCookie(new Cookie("articleUrl", "unicodeURL"));
```

and get the cookie & redirect the response like this :

```
Cookie articleUrl = getCookieByName(req ,"articleUrl");

if (articleUrl != null) {
    resp.sendRedirect(articleUrl.getValue());
} else {
    resp.sendRedirect("/");
}
```

But the browser don't respect if the URL contains Unicode character. Like if the URL contains 'ä' character then in browser it shows '%F6' which is not actual URL and show 404 error.

This works in Firefox browser but not in Chrome.

I aslo tried like the following way and get same result :

```
httpResponse.addCookie(new Cookie("articleUrl", URLEncode.encode("unicodeURL", "UTF-8")));
```

And

```
Cookie articleUrl = getCookieByName(req ,"articleUrl");

if (articleUrl != null) {
    resp.sendRedirect(URLDecode.decode(articleUrl.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
} else {
    resp.sendRedirect("/");
}
```

Can anyone please help.

Comment: The issue is likely in how the URL is being constructed. All non-ASCII letters must be percent-encoded as UTF-8. ä should become `%C3%A4`.

Comment: @McDowell I've encoded it also as UTF-8 as I described in the last portion and not work :(